# Accessing Controls in DataTemplate in ListBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, datatemplate

I have listbox which have DataTemplate.
I can not access controls which placed in the datatemplate.
How can I access to this controls?

```
<ListBox Height="344" Name="listBoxMedicine" Width="881">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <TextBlock Name="myTextBlock">
        </Datatemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: That`s not a very good idea to work with this controls. Better work with underlying objects (from `ItemsSource`) and use bindings or triggers to modify the way they`re shown. 
Why do yo need to access this controls?

Comment: Because of if bound field is have no data I want to set visibility of this control to hidden?Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: I think its better to refactor your data model, and do as @icebat suggest. Or you'll have logic in codebehind instead of having it in view/data models

Comment: @TabrizAtayi: how exactly do you need the visibility to change? Can you update your question with an explanation.

Comment: For example  I have 2 field and each caption. When one of the field data is null ,then i want to set visibility="hidden".
Did I explain my problem to you?

Answer (score 1):

If you still want access your controls in codebehaind, you can do something like this:

1) Add a new helper method somewhere:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Visual> ToVisualTree(this Visual visual)
    {
        yield return visual;

        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual);
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; ++i)
        {
            var child = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, i);

            if (child == null) yield break;

            foreach (var subItem in child.ToVisualTree())
            {
                yield return subItem;
            }                
        }
    }
```

2) Use it like this:

```
 var allTextBlocks = listBoxMedicine.ToVisualTree().OfType<TextBlock>().ToList();
```

But I still strongly recomend to refactor your data model.

Comment: VisualTreeHelper is defined in System.Windows.Media namespace

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments i would suggest you create a view-model which simply provides a property for the visbility, e.g.:

```
public class DataViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Data _data;
    // Some data property.
    public Data Data { get { return _data; } set { ... } }

    private Visibility _visibility;
    // The visibility property.
    public Visibility Visibility { get { return _visibility; } set { ... } }
}
```

You can then bind that visibility and later set it in code to affect the view:

```
<DataTemplate >
    <TextBlock Name="myTextBlock" Visibility="{Binding Visibility}">
</Datatemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this approach to get FrameworkElement from ItemsControl, also will work with ListBox, ListView because they all inherit from ItemsControl.

```
private void CheckBounds(ItemsControl itemsControl)
    {
        foreach (var item in itemsControl.Items)
        {
            var child = ((FrameworkElement)itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item));
            child.IsEnabled = child.IsControlVisible(itemsControl);
        }
    }
```